# Find the sum of integers in a list (of type integers) recursively (java)

Tags: java, list, recursion

I am trying to write a method which returns the sum of integers in a list of type integer. This is what I have so far,

```
    public int sum (List <Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return sum(list.subList(0, list.size()-1));
    }
}
```

However, this does not seem to work is there any problem with the code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where are you storing the sum though? You're just reducing the list but not calculating the sum of each element in the list.

Comment: @Ramesh I don't think I need to store the sum, do I?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use another variable...right now your code doesn't even add anything to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int sum (List <Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return list.get(list.size()-1) + sum(list.subList(0, list.size()-1));
    }
}
```

I needed to sum the last value of the list aswell, which is what

```
return list.get(list.size()-1) + sum(list.subList(0, list.size()-1));
```

achieves.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote sum([1,2,3,4]) = sum([1,2,3]) when in fact it is equal to (sum([1,2,3]) + 4).

Your code recursively computes the sum of the prefix of the list, but doesn't add the value of the last element.

Comment: thank you, I have figured it out by your explanation.